# Avoid Iframe Content Refresh during hide and unhide iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i have an issue i am calling an url in iframe but after calling i want hide or unhide the iframe  but whenever i hide and again unhide the iframe the frame gets reload again i want to avoid reloading
the iframe. the iframe is inside form tag runat="server".
help me.

.ASPX

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="col-32 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<button id="btnHd">hide() and show()</button>
</div>
<div id="myframe" runat="server">
<iframe src="http://serverip" name="myFrame" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0"></iframe>
</div>
</contentTemplate>
```

.CS

```
if (myFrame.Visible == false)
    {
        myFrame.Visible = true;
        showhidebutton.Text = "Hide";

    }
    else
    {
        myFrame.Visible = false;
        showhidebutton.Text = "Show";
    }
```